# How to subtract two times in shell

Tags: shell, shell-script, awk, date, arithmetic

I nee to subtract two lines which is in the format of time in shell.
The time format is hh:mm:ss
I used the code below to get the time.

```
cat /var/log/kern.log |grep usb |tail -2| awk '{print $3}'
```

The output of the above code is

```
18:23:24
18:20:20
```

How can I find the difference in seconds?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would take a step further (inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181712/simple-way-to-convert-002040-28-hoursminutesseconds-split-seconds-to-secon)):

```
# => 18:23:24 --> 66204
grep usb /var/log/kern.log|tail -2|awk '{print $3}'|awk -F: '{print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }'
```

So, after I had:

```
66204
66020
```

You could then do:

```
echo $((66204-66020)) # => 184
```

Comment: Why are you piping awk into awk ?

Comment: I'm separating concerns: the first `awk` gives me the hh:mm:ss format.  The second `awk` transforms the hhh:mm:ss into integers.  For me, it cuts down on cognitive load.

Comment: @DarkHeart: what would you recommend?

Answer (score 4):

A more general solution because it works with times from different dates, too:

```
echo "18:23:24
18:20:20" | 
  (read later_time; read former_time;
    former_seconds=$(date --date="$former_time" +%s);
    later_seconds=$(date --date="$later_time" +%s);
    echo $((later_seconds-former_seconds)) )
184
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `awk` you can do it in one invocation

```
awk '
/usb/{
("date +%s -d "$3)|getline t[++i];
}
END{
print t[i-1]-t[i];
}' /var/log/kern.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Your entire pipeline in awk without lots of unnecessary pipes.
Similar to costas but without using any external commands.

```
awk '/usb/{split($3,a,":");b[++x]=(a[1]*3600)+(a[2]*60)+a[3]}END{print b[x-1]-b[x]}' /var/log/kern.log
```

Heres just the last bit with the dates worked out if you decide to keep the pipes

```
 awk '{split($1,a,":");b[x++]=(a[1]*3600)+(a[2]*60)+a[3]}END{print b[0]-b[1]}'
```

Comment: @Costas, there are only ever going to be two at the end of that pipe so it works fine, also the $2 was a typo and has been fixed :)

Comment: Sorry I miss idea to remail all pipes